# How to select two tables compare them and get a single column value in PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]Track Table

[image]Follow Table

These are the two tables I have. I want to fetch 'post_id' from both the tables by comparing post_user_id and clicked_id with my session user id with both the tables.

I have tried this query.

```
   $lifestream = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM peoplelist_track t, peoplelist_follow f WHERE t.post_user_id != '$session_user_id' AND f.post_user_id != '$session_user_id'
                                                            AND t.clicked_id = '$session_user_id' AND f.clicked_id = '$session_user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
  $chk_lifestream = mysql_num_rows($lifestream);                                                             if($chk_lifestream > 0){
                                                           while($row_lifestream = mysql_fetch_array($lifestream)){
                                                        echo $post_id = $row_lifestream['post_id'];
                                                     }
                                                     }
```

Here $session_user_id = 9

Output I am getting is

25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
19
19
19
19
19
18
18
18
18
18

The numbers are repeating. But it should not.
I should get an output as 
25 19 18

Please help me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Yes tow tables are related

Comment: when your comparing `t.clicked_id` and `f.clicked_id` for equality wouldnt an `INNER JOIN` be more suitable for this task? `SELECT
  *
 FROM peoplelist_track t
 INNER JOIN peoplelist_follow f ON t.clicked_id = f.clicked_id
 WHERE
  t.clicked_id = '$session_user_id'
  AND t.post_user_id != '$session_user_id'
  AND f.post_user_id != '$session_user_id'`

Comment: Yes this is also showing the same result, but I don't need repeating post_id values, it must be distinct, so where I can use distinct here or any other solution?

Comment: sure you can add distinct just after the `SELECT` keyword, but that won't yield a really useful result if you select `*`, because it is likely that all rows are indeed distinct, try selecting only the columns you need (like `SELECT DISTINCT t.post_id, f.post_id FROM ...`

Comment: you are using deprecated mysql_* function (*in case you dont know)

Comment: SELECT t.post_user_id, t.clicked_id, f.post_user_id, f.clicked_id, DISTINCT t.post_id, f.post_id FROM peoplelist_track t, peoplelist_follow f WHERE t.post_user_id != '9' AND f.post_user_id != '9'
                AND t.clicked_id = '9' AND f.clicked_id = '9'

Comment: I tried this query but it showing syntax error.

Comment: @razor you need to add `DISTINCT` right after `SELECT`

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT t.post_user_id, t.clicked_id, f.post_user_id, f.clicked_id, t.post_id, f.post_id FROM peoplelist_track t, peoplelist_follow f WHERE t.post_user_id != '9' AND f.post_user_id != '9' AND t.clicked_id = '9' AND f.clicked_id = '9'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to join two tables then use the [UNION operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html%20UNION%20operator).

For example ([from w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)):

```
SELECT city 
FROM   customers 
UNION 
SELECT city 
FROM   suppliers 
ORDER  BY city;
```

Comment: I don't have any idea of that could you please help me out.

Comment: SELECT t.post_id FROM peoplelist_track t
WHERE t.post_user_id != '9' 
AND t.clicked_id = '9'
UNION
SELECT f.post_id FROM peoplelist_follow f
WHERE f.post_user_id != '9' 
AND f.clicked_id = '9'

Comment: UNION removes Duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/distinct-optimization.html) :

```
$lifestream = mysql_query("   SELECT DISTINCT(post_id)
                              FROM peoplelist_track t,
                                   peoplelist_follow f
                              WHERE t.post_user_id != '$session_user_id'
                                AND f.post_user_id != '$session_user_id'
                                AND t.clicked_id = '$session_user_id'
                                AND f.clicked_id = '$session_user_id'")
               or die(mysql_error());
```

It returns only the different values.

Comment: I know I can use distinct, but how to select other values I mean the post_user_id, clicked_id etc..If I use you query it is giving Column 'post_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: So I need the post_id values from both the tables.

Comment: I assumed you had the tables connected, check `Charlesliam` answer, he/she has showed how to connect.

Answer (score 0):

The table is not connected, try connecting them.

In this example try replacing `<parent_col>` with Parent table column and `<child_col>` with the Child table reference column.

```
$lifestream = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(POST_ID) FROM peoplelist_track t, peoplelist_follow f 
                           WHERE t.post_user_id != '$session_user_id' 
                           AND f.post_user_id != '$session_user_id'
                           AND t.clicked_id = '$session_user_id' 
                           AND f.clicked_id = '$session_user_id'
                           AND t.<parent_col> = f.<child_col>") 
                       or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: No sorry I don't want to connect them. Just I need distinct values. You can see the output only 24 should not print because in follow table post_user_id is equal to 9(which is session user id). You got it what I mean

Comment: @razor Yes `24` will not print because your track table's `post_user_id` does not have `9`!

Comment: Yes so How I can reframe the query to get the distincct values

Comment: @user007 Yes so How I can reframe the query to get the distincct values

Comment: I believe the answer will be distinct already if you connect the two table. And used the column you want in `Distinct`. I replace my `*` with `POST_ID` as user007 presented on his/her `Distinct` statement.

Comment: Okay fine if I use parent column. Do you mean parent column in track table is post_id and parent column in follow table is post_id?

Comment: Like t.post_id = f.post_id?

Comment: check the table column that reference the other table

Comment: try running `DESC <table_name>` to see the column name with data type description

Comment: So I have one more main table should I need to include that table too?